# Mobile User Registration

Tags: user-registration, mobile, android

I am writing an android (and eventually iphone) app that is proposing to register a user to a wordpress site. The intent is to have the user registration solely through the mobile device and not through a website front end. The app will update the wordpress site and the user will be able to login in to see his data. I have a general idea on how to use the wp hooks with json to do the mobile registration. However, is there a way to the registration process without enabling "anyone can register" in "general/settings"? (note: I looked through all the questions using "Mobile User Registration" but did not see any related.). Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at XML-RPC, then please come back and file an [edit] with your research and your try/errors.

Comment: Had you _tried_ it? I am not sure this setting actually prevents you from creating user with code.

Comment: I'm in the process of setting up an android app (Was hoping to get an answer first :-) ). My impression from the code at the link below is that the setting is as you suspect. http://android.svn.wordpress.org/tags/2.0/src/org/wordpress/android/AddAccount.java

Answer (score 1):

New users CAN be allowed to register remotely without setting "anyone can register" in "general/settings". The client is android and in addition to the android java client code using the 'org.xmlrpc library', the following was added to 'functions.php' in the child theme:

```
function xml_add_method( $methods ) {
    $methods['xxx.wp_create_user'] = 'xxx_wp_create_user';
    return $methods;
}

add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'xml_add_method');

function xxx_wp_create_user( $args ) {
    $uname = $args[1];
    $pword = $args[2];
    $email = $args[3];
   $user_id = wp_create_user( $uname, $pword, $email ); 
   return $user_id;
}
```